# How to click on a div and don't trigger the a action on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml

I've got something like this:

```
- @moves.each do |move|
  = link_to move do
    .move-item
      .btn-group
        .move-wishlist
        .move-checklist
      .move-image
      .move-text
        .move-title= move.name
        .move-description
          Some good description of the move.
```

And I've got those `.move-wishlist` and `.move-checklist` that are some divs that shows an selected/unselected image. What I want to do is: when I click on any of those divs I want to stop the link_to trigger and just run the click trigger for those divs. Maybe something related to jquery, but I can't really figure out how.

Any help would be very appreciated :)

Comment: `event.PreventDefault()` ?

Comment: USe event.stopPropagation()

Comment: As simple as a false `return false` on the click event of the A tag: `= link_to move, onclick: 'return false;' do [...]` --- You can also do something else before returing false: `onclick: 'alert("clicked!"); return false;'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere you defined a callback function for your divs, such as (assuming jquery):

```
    $('.move-wishlist').bind('click', function(e) {
        // ... your action here
    });
```

you just need to add

```
e.preventDefault();
```

inside the function to prevent the click event to go up and reach your link.

The complete event code:

```
$('.move-wishlist').bind('click', function(e) {
    // ... your action here
    e.preventDefault();   
});
```